# How to fix laravel & vue.js error in my project

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I get get the application to show the quiz page. the sample quiz in the code should display to the user however i cant seem to get the main page and vue.js to link together in laravel.

ive been able to get it working on notepad++ in one file, however when i bring it to my laravel project it doesnt work. As it needs to be in two different files

PHP code:

```
      <h1>{{ quiz.title }}</h1>
      <!-- index is used to check with current question index -->
      <div v-for="(question, index) in quiz.questions">
        <!-- Hide all questions, show only the one with index === to current question index -->
        <div v-show="index === questionIndex">
          <h2>{{ question.text }}</h2>
          <ol>
            <li v-for="response in question.responses">
              <label>
                <!-- The radio button has three new directives -->
                <!-- v-bind:value sets "value" to "true" if the response is correct -->
                <!-- v-bind:name sets "name" to question index to group answers by question -->
                <!-- v-model creates binding with userResponses -->
                <input type="radio" 
                       v-bind:value="response.correct" 
                       v-bind:name="index" 
                       v-model="userResponses[index]"> {{response.text}}
              </label>
            </li>
          </ol>
          <!-- The two navigation buttons -->
          <!-- Note: prev is hidden on first question -->
          <button v-if="questionIndex > 0" v-on:click="prev">
            prev
          </button>
          <button v-on:click="next">
            next
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div v-show="questionIndex === quiz.questions.length">
        <h2>
        Quiz finished
      </h2>
        <p>
          Total score: {{ score() }} / {{ quiz.questions.length }}
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>`



    Vue.js code:
    '// Create a quiz object with a title and two questions.
    // A question has one or more answer, and one or more is valid.
    var quiz = {
      title: 'My quiz',
      questions: [
        {
          text: "Question 1",
          responses: [
            {text: 'Wrong, too bad.'}, 
            {text: 'Right!', correct: true}, 
          ]
        }, {
          text: "Question 2",
          responses: [
            {text: 'Right answer', correct: true}, 
            {text: 'Wrong answer'}, 
          ]
        } 
      ]
    };

    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        quiz: quiz,
        // Store current question index
        questionIndex: 0,
        // An array initialized with "false" values for each question
        // It means: "did the user answered correctly to the question n?" "no".
        userResponses: Array(quiz.questions.length).fill(false)
      },
      // The view will trigger these methods on click
      methods: {
        // Go to next question
        next: function() {
          this.questionIndex++;
        },
        // Go to previous question
        prev: function() {
          this.questionIndex--;
        },
        // Return "true" count in userResponses
        score: function() {
          return this.userResponses.filter(function(val) { return val }).length;
        }
      }
    });
```

The user should be displayed the question the choose an answer click next, choose the next answer then the result of the quiz will display to the user.

Comment: use `@{{ }}` for vue string interpolations while using it in blade templates, since blade uses `{{ }}` as it's own string interpolation. Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#blade-and-javascript-frameworks

Comment: thanks that has worked to an extent.... now the application just shows the @{{}} aspects on the web page